# ScaleGestureDetector not detecting two finger movements in Android 4.2

Tags: android, multi-touch

I have class that implements `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener`. On devices running Android 4.1 and earlier, the methods `(OnScaleBegin, OnScale, and OnScaleEnd)` get called for just about every two finger swipe movement. This was useful to me, since I use two finger swipes for both panning and zooming (scaling) functionality. I use the `currentSpan` in the `ScaleGestureDetector` to determine whether the user intends to pan or zoom. As of Android 4.2, it seems, the `OnScale`... methods only get called when the span change between pointers exceeds an OS-determined threshold.

Are others seeing this? Is there a way to manipulate the OS-determined threshold?

The other `GestureDetector` options only respond to single pointer events. Is there a best practice for detecting multi-pointer movement events in a way that supports both 4.2 and pre-4.2 OS versions?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I settled on using the `ScaleGestureDetector` for zoom functionality and a condition in the View's `onTouchEvent()` to handle pan. I set a flag when I'm zooming to prevent pan. Code extracts included below. It's not quite as slick as when I could zoom and pan simultaneously, but it's a solution I can live with.

----within view class----

```
ScaleListener zoomListener = new ScaleListener();

public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent motion)
{
    zoomListener.onTouchEvent(motion);

    int actionMasked = motion.getActionMasked();
    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && motion.getPointersDown() > 1)
    {
        if (!_zoomMode)
        {
            // If more than one pointer is involved in a move event, 
            // and zoom mode is not set, we assume that the user is panning.
            // A zoom gesture movement should be handled by the ScaleGestureDetector
            doPan();
        }
    }
}
```

----Inner Class----

```
class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{
     public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
     {
        setZoomMode(true);
        doZoom();
     } 

     public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
     {
         setZoomMode(false);
     }
}
```

Comment: but how did you do the doPan() from the motionEvent? what threashold did you set for the currentspan ? I have the same problem as yours.It would be nice if you could help.Thanks

Comment: The `doPan()` is proprietary to my employer. It's the code that actually manipulates the shapes I'm working with. I'm not using `currentspan` anymore because I rely on the ScaleListener to determine if zoom is indicated.

Comment: Thanks for the same.I understand the doPan() cannot be shared.I do have a question.. Is there a way to differentiate between scale and a pan.When there is a slight out of sync movement between two fingers (during pan) the scaleGestureDetector kicks in.So it keeps on zooming until the user takes his finger off.. THis is really a problem and I could not solve it.. How did you tackle this?

Comment: I'm not sure my solution will address the problem you describe since zoom will always trump pan if Android determines that a zoom is taking place and calls the `onScale()` method. In the devices I've tested with, the Android-determined span threshold for zoom has been big enough to allow successful panning in most cases. One caveat, though, I've mostly been testing on tablets as opposed to phones. Wish I had a more helpful solution to offer.